# how to use xsl to transform this xml file

Tags: xml, xml-parsing, xslt-2.0

My Boss gave me a xml file. after that told me, use java servlet or any thing that can transform xml file to html. I find some infomation about processing XML and xsl also.
with some easy example. my code can run and have a output file ( html ). But with this file, i cant get value of elements.

Here is my xml file

```
<OMeS>
  <PMSetup  startTime="2013-05-14T23:00:00.000+07:00:00" interval="60">
    <PMMOResult>
      <MO>
        <DN><![CDATA[PLMN-PLMN/RNC-14]]></DN>
      </MO>
      <MO>
        <DN><![CDATA[PLMN-PLMN/HOS-14/SCID-51321]]></DN>
      </MO>
      <MO>
        <DN><![CDATA[PLMN-PLMN/MCC-452/MNC-1]]></DN>
      </MO>
      <MO>
        <DN><![CDATA[PLMN-PLMN/LAC-20180/CI-51393]]></DN>
      </MO>
      <MO>
        <DN><![CDATA[PLMN-PLMN/MCC-452/MNC-1]]></DN>
      </MO>
      <PMTarget  measurementType="AutoDef_ISHO_v2">
        <M1015C0>21</M1015C0>
        <M1015C1>21</M1015C1>
        <M1015C2>6927</M1015C2>
        <M1015C3>224</M1015C3>
        <M1015C4>45890</M1015C4>
        <M1015C5>25</M1015C5>
      </PMTarget>
    </PMMOResult>
    <PMMOResult>
      <MO>
        <DN><![CDATA[PLMN-PLMN/RNC-14]]></DN>
      </MO>
      <MO>
        <DN><![CDATA[PLMN-PLMN/HOS-14/SCID-51393]]></DN>
      </MO>
      <MO>
        <DN><![CDATA[PLMN-PLMN/MCC-452/MNC-1]]></DN>
      </MO>
      <MO>
        <DN><![CDATA[PLMN-PLMN/LAC-20180/CI-51393]]></DN>
      </MO>
      <MO>
        <DN><![CDATA[PLMN-PLMN/MCC-452/MNC-1]]></DN>
      </MO>
      <PMTarget  measurementType="AutoDef_ISHO_v2">
        <M1015C0>29</M1015C0>
        <M1015C1>29</M1015C1>
        <M1015C2>8385</M1015C2>
        <M1015C3>239</M1015C3>
        <M1015C4>62130</M1015C4>
        <M1015C5>37</M1015C5>
      </PMTarget>
    </PMMOResult>



  </PMSetup>
</OMeS>
```

Here is my xsl file

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

<xsl:template match="/">
  <html>
  <body>
  <h2>My data</h2>
    <table border="1">
      <tr bgcolor="#9acd32">
        <th>MO</th>
      </tr>
      <xsl:for-each select="OMeS/PMSetup/PMMOResult">
      <tr>
        <td>
                    <xsl:value-of select="MO/DN"/>
        </td>
      </tr>
      </xsl:for-each>
    </table>
  </body>
  </html>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

I use java servlet to transform this xml to html. so, it shows no thing. Please help me !
and have any tut for xsl that i can learn ?

Comment: Try this http://bit.ly/15IQkeL

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When I add the missing xsl:stylesheet start tag to your code

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
```

it runs just fine.

If that really was your error, then you need to look at how you are running the code to make sure that the next time you make a simple mistake, you display the diagnostics somewhere you can see them. Generally I would debug a stylesheet in some IDE or command line environment rather than "in situ" as a servlet.

Comment: It looks like that was a mistake in formatting the code for SO rather than an actual error. But the point still stands - debug using a standalone tool before you try integrating it in your servlet.

Comment: I just wanna get data in this xml file and show them to browers. But it shows no thing :(. It still works but has no thing to show

Comment: Yes, we know what you want. But showing us code which is different from the code you were running isn't a good way to get help. Take more care.

Comment: sorry. I forget to add <?xml version="1.0"?> in the top of xml file. How can i get data of DN or M1015C5 in xml to show ? 
<xsl:for-each select="OMeS/PMSetup/PMMOResult">
      <tr>
        <td>
                    <xsl:value-of select="MO/DN"/>
        </td>
      </tr>
      </xsl:for-each>
Where is error ???

Comment: I already told you, with the addition of the xsl:stylesheet start tag the code works for me. So it must be the way you are running it. So tell us how you are running it.

Comment: It's generally considered good practice when you solve a problem to post a description of your solution, so others who come across the question later can see what happened.